# Select box selected value show inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select, drop-down-menu

Code:

-> option "id" values to display

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#price").change(function() {
var id = $(this).children('option:selected').attr('id');
});
</script>

<td>
<select name="money" id="price" style="width: 100%">
<option value="Low" id="10">Low</option>
<option value="Middle" id="30" >Middle</option>
<option value="High" id="60" >High</option>
<option value="Highest" id="100" >Highest</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<span id="price"></span>
</td>
```

This does not give me the desired results.

Comment: Where is the `div` you are talking about? And I don't see that you put the value anywhere...

Comment: It's working, once you remove the slashes -- it's just not DOING anything. Remove, the slashes, then add something like console.log(id) so you can see that it does do something.

Comment: Or, alternatively, let us know what you EXPECT it to do.

Comment: code is not working :/

Comment: Oh, boy. Wait. WHICH #price are you expecting to watch? When the select is changed, the change is triggered. Why do you have a span with the same ID? That never changes! I'm so confused.

Comment: What is the purpose of this script? getting the selected option's id value? And then what are you gonna do? Also why did you put slash before the single quote?

Comment: To avoid conflicts with php codes

Answer (score 0):

Saying "code is not working" does absolutely nothing. Works fine for me, **[here it is as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/pnbbxmre/)**.

```js
$("#price").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).children('option:selected').attr('id');
  $("#priceDisplay").append("<p>Price chosen: "+id+"</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <select name="money" id="price" style="width: 100%">
    <option value="Low" id="10">Low</option>
    <option value="Middle" id="30">Middle</option>
    <option value="High" id="60">High</option>
    <option value="Highest" id="100">Highest</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <span id="priceDisplay"></span>
</td>
```

Edited to include the jQuery, as specified.
Edited a second time, to change the name of the span and to append the information into that span each time the select is changed.

Comment: what is the behavior you are expecting. It's doing exactly what I told it to do, given what you've told us. Are you wanting the value from the select to appear in the span?

Comment: rerun the above snippet, I've edited it to do exactly that.

Comment: Your different example is toggling divs based on the selection from the dropdown. The HTML you've given doesn't support that. If all you're looking to do is to display the data, either Jonas or I have given pretty much the same answer. And we're both right. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to show the result?

```
$("#price").change(function() {
 var id = $(this).children('option:selected').attr('id');    
console.log(id);
$("#showprice").html(id);
});

<span id="showprice"></span>
```